# Find tag associated with high num valuesJavascript logic function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of objects, calculate the tag that produces the highest "num" most often.

I'm having an issue where the num represents level of happiness, and I'm trying to find the tag that leads to the highest level most often.

Example of array:

`[{num: 5, tags:["friends", "family"]}, {num: 1, tags:["friends", "work"]}, {num: 4, tags:["school"]}]`

The family tag would get a lot of points cause it appears with a 5. Friends would get points too, but then be disadvantaged because of the one.

This problem is supposed to be a little obscure. There's no one way to do it. If you have any suggestions for how, please leave a comment! If you have code, even better:).

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Do you want to find which tags are associated most often with high `num` values?

Comment: Yes, @SimonBrahan That would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like homework or a job interview question, so I'm going to make suggestions rather than full solutions.

You have an input data structure; think about what your output data structure should look like.  Coding then becomes a simple matter of transforming one to the other.

One possibility is a simple object, treating the tags as keys and their num as values, something like:

`{friends: 5, family: 5, work: 1...}`

...but this means you have to make decisions about what happens when the same tag has more than one value.  Do you only care about the highest value for a given tag? Do you want the average of all values? Do you want a [confidence interval](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/confidence-interval/)?  (i.e. if there are fifteen instances of tag A, and only one instances of tag B, the values for A are more likely to be "correct".) This is the part that requires some interpretation of the question.

So that implies that instead of keeping track of only a single value for each tag, maybe you need to keep track of all of them, so for every tag you'll be able to see how many scores it received, and what they were:

`{friends: [1, 5], family: [5], work: [1]...}`

...and then as a final pass can go through those arrays and perform whatever interpretation of the data you decided on above, resulting in a single number for each tag.

So now that you know what you're converting to, the algorithm is pretty obvious:

- Initialize an output object
- for each object in the source array,

  - for each tag in the object's "tag",

    - if the tag doesn't exist yet in the output object, create it as a new object key, with an empty array as its value
    - push the "num" value onto that array
- for each key in the output object,

  - Do Something™ to its values array to convert it into a single value

Comment: Well, anything's possible, but it looks pretty clear to me @raythe.  You may want to refer to the FAQ; there's a long-standing [community consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on how to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thank you for the in-depth idea! This isn't homework or anything, I'm just building an app and wanted to include some cool stats from user input! This was a confusing problem for me, but it's one I really liked

Comment: Very happy to help!

Answer (score -1):

Pretty easy with the lodash `countBy` function.

```
const theArray = [{num: 5, tags:["friends", "family"]}, {num: 1, tags:["friends", "work"]}, {num: 4, tags:["school"]}];

const allTags = [];

theArray.map((item) =>{
allTags.push(...item.tags);
} );

const count = _.countBy(allTags);

console.log(count);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m7L1prau/